# Timezone Calculation Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am making a countdown timer and I want it to globally countdown to Christmas.  Therefore I have my timestamp value of 1387929600 which is dec 25 00:00:00.  I am adjusting that value according to the different time zones and I am doing it like this:

```
NSDate *firstDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1387954801];

    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    int tzInt = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate:firstDate];

    int timeDifference = tzInt+1387954801;

    xmasDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeDifference];
```

I take the `firstDate` and do `secondsFromGMTForDate` and then add it to the original timestamp number to get the `xmasDate` adjusted for time zones.

This general approach seems to work however the `secondsFromGMTForDate` is not calculating correctly.

For example when I set my phone to the current time zone it still wants to subtract `"-25200"` from the timestamp time when it should be zero since its the current time zone.

Am I correct in saying that?  I might be missing something in the calculation and maybe I have to add to the timestamp number but I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since when did Christmas start at noon plus one second? Christmas starts at 25 December, 00:00:00.

Comment: sorry your right typo I was thinking AM.  Timestamp is correct

Answer (score 1):

By **adding** tzInt to a timestamp in GMT, you're doubling the effect of time zone difference instead of cancelling it.

For example, if your timezone is 25200 seconds behind GMT (tzInt=-25200), you need to add 25200 to 1387929600, as Christmas will come later in your time zone.
So the correct calculation of timeDifference is the following:

```
int timeDifference = 1387954801 - tzInt;
```

Otherwise the code looks correct, but I'd use the following code instead, which, I think, is easier to understand:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:25];
[components setMonth:12];
[components setYear:2013];
NSDate *xmasDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

NSTimeInterval secondsLeft = [xmasDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```